# How to change ReturnUrl in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

Question may be confused I'm trying to make it clear. I have HomeController class and in this controller I have `[HttpGet] Details` and authorized `[HttpPost] AddComment` functions. I don't have separated AddComment view cause I just use simple textarea to add comment in Details view and a button "Add comment" which calls "Home/AddComment" function to post comment.

In Details view Url is "Home/Details/7". When user write comment and click "Add comment" button, if he has not logged-in, he's redirected to Account/Login view.

In LoginView returnUrl is "/Home/AddComment" and after successful login normally user is redirected to /Home/AddComment view. But here I want user redirect to "Home/Details/7" url again and now he is authorized and can post comment.

[image]

Comment: If you redirect the user to `Home/Details/7` after login, he will loose the comments he typed previously and will be required to type again, which is not very good user experience.

Comment: in real project before user post comment i check if user is authorized if not he can't see textarea to write comment . for now i just keep things simple. in all cases i need the user to redirect current book details view

Comment: Ok then in Login Action method always redirect to details page on successful login

Comment: yes but i can't take "id" parameter to redirect to the same book details. all i do is just in login method to check if(returnUrl==/home/addcomment){returnUrl=Book/Details/?} and what about id parameter? but even if it possible i think it is not a good practise. cause in login view Url shows returnUrl home/addcomment but user redirects to book/details/7 view

Comment: no, you get the querystring which will give you 'Home/AddComment/7' and then get the id using substring, lastindexof

Comment: i got it but in login view Url is "Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fhome%2Faddcomment" as seen user expecting to redirect to home/addcomment view but book details view comes up and i think it is not that good approach. is this only proper or the best way to achieve this?